# Is a 1-100 scale categorical or continuous variable?

Tags: r, regression

I have a project using multivariate regression in R studio. Is a 1-100 scale which measures the environmental performance of a country categorical or continuous? How should I treat it in R?

Comment: When you say multivariate regression do you mean multiple regression? Not that it affects the question, but that's a common confusion;,

Comment: Im not sure I'm just using the word my uni said, I am very new to this. I have X,Y, and Z

Comment: Being a learner is fine, but you still need to take some responsibility for your own learning! One outcome, two predictors = (multiple) regression. Two outcomes, one predictor = multivariate regression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Technically* if the only outcomes are between 1 and 100 and it is impossible to have an outcome like 2.5, then this would be categorical.

That being said, there might be little penalty in modelling the outcome as a continuous variable. It depends on what the analysis is and what you intend to investigate.

EDIT:

After looking at the data, you can do linear regression on your outcome.  The outcome is *not* categorical, it contains rational numbers (e.g. 65.9).  If the outcome is bounded between 0 and 100, there will not likely be any ceiling effects since the outcome is observed to be between 30 and 70.  In summary, linear regression should be fine.

Comment: Hi, Demetri I am using multivariate regression

Comment: Fit the model and examine the diagnostics.  If any of the measures are close to 0 or 100 you may have floor/ceiling effects and the model may give unrealistic predictions.

Comment: Hi what measures are you talking about? sorry I'm very inexperienced in R. I could provide measurements if that helps

Comment: Sure, just provide the data

Comment: Hi Demetri, what is the best way to do this with the numbers all being in a spreadsheet? each time I try to copy and paste it, the numbers turn into an image

Comment: With data in a spreadsheet, maybe save it to a .csv file and include or link to that file?

Comment: https://www.gu.se/en/quality-government/qog-data/data-downloads/standard-dataset here is the dataset. My outcome or Y variable is epi_epi. My explanatory or X is fh_ppp. My Z is bti_ep. Let me know if this works or not. Again thanks all for the help

Comment: There are two versions on offer there, time series or cross section. Which are you using?

Comment: Cross sectional @NickCox

Comment: @LouisRich see my edits.  And in the future, I would encourage you to be more patient with members of the community.  We only want to help, and sometimes that means re-examining what you've asked.

Comment: thank you. Sorry guys, I didn't fully understand and that came across the wrong way. Appreciate your patience